# Using Intent.createChooser and getting error: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, service

I want to open the share via option from the service class.
It is working fine in Android 7, but in 8+ OS it starts showing

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

I have also included this flag to my Intent, but it's still showing the same error.

Is there any other way to open share via option from the service class?

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, rasta);  //rasta -> Uri obj
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    getApplicationContext().startService(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share karna..."));
```

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project, if that doesn't help try adding that flag into the manifest, maybe your both activities need that flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Intent.createChooser` creates an `Intent`, so you need to set the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag on *that* intent, e.g.,

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, rasta);  //rasta -> Uri obj
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i,"Share karna...");
                    chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

You were also calling `startService` instead of `startActivity` - make sure to correct that as well.

Comment: Thank you sir it solved my problem. I have one more query, till now my webView was working fine, but now it showing error 
WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
is there any relation with this intent?( as i m using this intent inside the downloadmanager of webView)

Comment: I'm glad it helped! That almost certainly has no relation to this Intent code - that would be related to content within the web page itself, while this is outside of it.